# Shiny Table that Updates via sliderInput

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having trouble creating a dynamic table that produces a calculated field based on four sliderInput controls, where the once sliderInput determines the length of the dataframe.

```
library(shiny)
# Define server logic for random distribution application

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

sliderValues <- reactive ({
    #compose data frame
      ws<- as.numeric (c(0:input$sws))
      df<-data.frame(
      WindSpeed = as.character (c(ws)
      ),
      CBH = as.character (c(input$sCBH)
                          ),
      FFMC = as.character(c(input$sFFMC)
                          ),
      DC = as.character (c(input$sDC)
                         ),
      PCFI = as.character (c((exp(-66.62+(-0.993*input$sCBH)+(0.568*ws)+(0.671*input$sFFMC)+(0.018*input$sDC)))/(1+(exp(-66.62+(-0.993*input$sCBH)+(0.568*input$sws)+(0.671*input$sFFMC)+(0.018*input$sDC)))))
                        )

      )
    return(df)

})

#Show the values using an HTML table
  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()

  })

})
```

Basically I would like to use renderTable to produce a table that multiplies the fields in PCFI based on the other sliderInputs.  However, currently by using ws<- as.numeric (c(0:input$sws)), it is multiplying the entire list by the variables.  I've been trying all day to produce the correct product, so any help would be amazing.

```
shinyUI
  (fluidPage(
titlePanel("Behaviour Model"),

#Sidebar with sliders that demonstrate various available 
#options
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      #Simple integer interval
      sliderInput ("sws", "10m Wind Speed (km/hr):",
                   min=0,
                   max=50,
                   value=15),
      sliderInput ("sCBH", "Crown Base Height (m):",
                   min=0,
                   max=25,
                   value=5),
      sliderInput ("sFFMC", "Fine Fuel Moisutre Code:",
                   min = 77,
                   max=98,
                   value = 88,
                   step=1.0),
      sliderInput("sDC", "Drought Code:",
                  min=0,
                  max= 1000,
                  value = 200)
      ),

    #Show a table summarizing the values entered
    mainPanel(
        tableOutput("values")
        )
    )
))
```

Ideally, in the end I will have a table that resembles the following and not have the PCFI field calculate the entirety of the ws<- as.numeric (c(0:input$sws)), just the single increment in windspeed per line:

```
WindSpeed    CBH        FFMC      DC       PCFI
0             5          88       200      *calculated field*
1             5          88       200      *calculated field*
2             5          88       200      *calculated field*
3             5          88       200      *calculated field*
4             5          88       200      *calculated field*
5             5          88       200      *calculated field*
...           ...
Length Dependent on Windspeed Slider, as each record is calculated in +1km/hr increments.
```

Once again, I really appreciate any help on this.
Kevin

This is what the output table should look like:

```
CBH WindSpeed   FFMC    DC  PCFI
4   0             92    200 0.005168453
4   1             92    200 0.009085037
4   2             92    200 0.015922053
4   3             92    200 0.027760177
4   4             92    200 0.047970947
4   5             92    200 0.081660255
4   6             92    200 0.135638245
4   7             92    200 0.216870104
4   8             92    200 0.328274418
4   9             92    200 0.46306739
4   10            92    200 0.60348325
```

Comment: I don't get what your desired output is. I get a table similar to what you indicated. What precisely is wrong?

Comment: Hi @nicola, thanks for looking at the question.  It seems that the PCFI is calculating the output based on the entire range of input$sws, when I want each record to calculate PCFI individually based on 1km/hr increments.  For instance, PCFI should be equal to 0.46306739 when Windspeed= 9, CBH= 4, FFMC=92, and DC=200.

Comment: @nicola, I added a table of what the outputs are supposed to look like for PCFI

Comment: I think I got it. Just replace `(0.568*input$sws)` with `(0.568*ws)` in the calculation of `PCFI`.

Comment: @nicola, mannnn I can't believe I didn't think of that!  How simple!  Thank you so much for your help, sometimes it just takes a pair of fresh eyes.  I am forever grateful :). Kevin